# how to add instance to the list and then to the listbox in windows form

Tags: c#, list, listbox

I don't know how to add Instances of my `Album` class from `TextBoxes` to a `List<Album>` and then to a `ListBox` in my WindowsForm.

Here is the code I have written so far but I'm stuck here and I don't know what to do next.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    List<Album> AlbumList = new List<Album>();

    private void TrackButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addTracks settingsForm = new addTracks();
        settingsForm.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void CreateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Album g = new Album (ASINtextBox.Text, AlbumNametextBox.Text, ArtisttextBox.Text, 
            ReleaseDatePicker.Text, LabeltextBox.Text, ImagetextBox.Text);

        AlbumList.Add(g);
    }
}
```

I dont have eny error i just think it is not creating a new list when I'm debuging the program.

This is the code for the class:

```
eclass Album
{
    private string ASIN;
    private string AlbumName;
    private string Artist;
    private string ReleaseDate;
    private string Label;
    private string Image;

    public Album(int ASIN)
    {
        this.ASIN = "no value";
        this.AlbumName = "no value";
        this.Artist = "no value";
        this.ReleaseDate = "no value";
        this.Label = "no value";
        this.Image = "no value";
    }

    public Album(string ASIN, string AlbumName, string Artist, string ReleaseDate, 
        string Label, string Image)
    {
        this.ASIN = ASIN;
        this.AlbumName = AlbumName;
        this.Artist = Artist;
        this.ReleaseDate = ReleaseDate;
        this.Label = Label;
        this.Image = Image;
    }   

    public string aSIN
    {
        get { return this.ASIN; }
        set { ASIN = value; }
    }

    public string albumName
    {
        get { return this.AlbumName; }
        set { AlbumName = value; }
    }

    public string artist
    {
        get { return this.Artist; }
        set { Artist = value; }
    }

    public string createDate
    {
        get { return this.ReleaseDate; }
        set { ReleaseDate = value; }

    }

    public string label
    {
        get { return this.Label; }
        set { Label = value; }
    }

    public string image
    {
        get { return this.Image; }
        set { Image = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: What are the properties for your Album class?

Comment: What's not working? It looks like you're already creating a new Album and adding it to the list in the `CreateButton_Click` event.

Comment: @RufusL  edited, there is the class

Comment: @DanCundy i dont have error just dont see anything being added to list when im debuging the program

Comment: Why do you not set the ASIN in the first constructor that takes one as a parameter?

Comment: Also, you should consider using auto-properties if all you're doing is getting and setting private fields. For example, you only need: `public string Artist { get; set; }`

Comment: You don't see them added to the `AlbumList`, or the `ListBox`, or both?

Comment: @RufusL I don't see anything in being added into albumlist but i dont know how to connect the list with the listbox

Comment: Do you mean when you set a breakpoint on `AlbumList.Add(g);` and press `F10` when it breaks, the list is still empty? That seems impossible. The answer below shows one way to clear the list box and add the list items to it.

Comment: @RufusL oh i was setting breakpoint at the wrong place now it is working I can see the thing being added into the List thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you've got a few different options, but the easiest is something like this:

```
private void RefreshListBox()
{
    myGuiListBox.Items.Clear();
    foreach(Album loopAlbum in this.AlbumList)
    {
        myGuiListBox.Items.Add(loopAlbum.ToString());
    }
}
```

... then, whenever something would change the list box (such as creating a new album and adding it to your List<>), you simply call the RefreshListBox() function.

Comment: Is the the way to connect the list with the listbox in the form? sorry for stupid questions I'm just new to the c# and sometimes confused because I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the listbox by not adding in the list box but just showing the values through the labels.

```
private void ShowAlbumsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int temp = AlbumList.Count();
        string talbumname = "";
        string talbumasin = "";
        string talbumartist = "";
        string talbumrelease = "";
        string talbumlabel = "";
        for (int n =0; n<temp;n++)
        {
            talbumname = talbumname + AlbumList[n].albumName;
            talbumname = talbumname + '\n';

           talbumasin = talbumasin + AlbumList[n].aSIN;
            talbumasin = talbumasin + '\n';

            talbumartist = talbumartist + AlbumList[n].artist;
            talbumartist = talbumartist + '\n';

            talbumrelease = talbumrelease + AlbumList[n].createDate;
            talbumrelease = talbumrelease + '\n';

            talbumlabel = talbumlabel + AlbumList[n].label;
            talbumlabel = talbumlabel + '\n';

        }
        label8.Text = talbumname;

        label7.Text = talbumasin;

        label9.Text = talbumartist;

        label10.Text = talbumrelease;

        label11.Text = talbumlabel;
    }
```

thanks everyone for help.